# Metric Which Induces Distance From Set of Points Equal to Arbitrary Function on Boundary of Connected Set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Say I have a closed, connected set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R} ^d$, and a finite set of points in its interior $S \subset X^\circ$. I am interested in considering under what conditions there exists a metric, $d$, on $X$ where the distance from each point on the the boundary of $X$, $\partial X$, to $S$ is equal to an arbitrary function $f$ defined on $\partial X$. That is, under what conditions on $X$, $S$, and $f$, does there exist a metric $d$ on $X$ such that for $\forall x \in \partial X$, $f(x) = min_{s \in S} d(s, x)$.

Continuity of $f$ is an obvious necessary condition, but that's about all I've got. I'd appreciate any insight into any sufficient conditions, whether they be on $X$, $S$, or $f$, to guarantee that such a metric exists. Has this problem been studied before? A specific case I am interested in is where $f$ is constant- what are sufficient conditions on $X$ and $S$ for this to be achieved?

$S$ can be assumed to be a singleton if that simplifies anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A fairly specific example. If $S$ is a singleton containing the origin, and if $X$ is the closure of its interior, $X$ is convex, and $x \in X$ implies $-x \in X$, and if $f$ is constant (say $f=1$), then you can define a norm as follows. If $y=O$ then $||y||=0$, otherwise if $\alpha y$ is on the boundary of $X$ then $||y||=\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Some other functions of $||y||$ would give a different (but equivalent) metric.